# Pass back reference to an injected service class from where it's implemented

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wonder if it's possible to pass back a reference from a component class that have a custom interface implemented to the injected service class in my Angular 6 project?

Example of what I want.

**ServiceClass**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private parent: MyComponent){ // <- Get back a reference from the component I inject this into, somehow?
        parent.doStuff();
    }
}
```

**ComponentClass**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'project-a-component',
  template: `
    <div>stuff</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService){ }

    doStuff(): void {
        console.log('yey!');
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
What I want to archive is a way to listen to OnDestroy event for a component to be able to run .pipe(takeUntil(parent.isDestroyed)) to unsubscribe a subscription without implementing it in every place I uses my services on in my project. Or have to pass a reference to my parent component in every method call. A way to have the reference in the constructor (or just a single place) would be awesome. So I tried to explain my problem in a relevant and easy way as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't even try to do that. Components are not meant to be injected in services. Maybe tell us what you are trying to achieve and maybe we can advice another way. :)

Comment: See my edited message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that I used to manage this where to have a method in my service that takes the components interface and set it to a variable inside it own. I just have to run this method in ngOnInit() everywhere where I uses it. It reduce lot of code from my components and feels like a valid way to do it.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private component: MyComponent;

    constructor(){}

    setMyComponent(component: MyComponent): void {
        this.component = component;
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'project-a-component',
  template: `
    <div>stuff</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService){
        myService.setMyComponent(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88 So you can make your own version, hook into the `OnDestroy` in components and do whatever you want to do:

```
export function MyDecorator( constructor ) {
  const original = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;
  constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
    if (this.myService) {
      // do stuff!
    }
  };
}
```

Of course you can use the same sample as in the article, that will unsubscribe all subscriptions, which is of course desirable, not only for a single service! :)

Then import this to your component and mark the decorator on your component:

```
@MyDecorator
export class MyComponent {
// ...
```